# Print option for each item in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and for each item in the array, I'm trying to add in a new `<option>`.

To do so, I've tried the following:

```
 array.forEach(function(arr) {
   console.log(array);
   $(".filterSection .department").append('<option value="'+array+'">'+array+'</option>');
 });
```

However, the option is just printing with all the array values in the `<option>`. It creates new `option` tags, but their value and text is all the items in the array.

Full demo:

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];

array.forEach(function(arr) {
  console.log(array);
  $(".department").append('<option value="' + array + '">' + array + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="department" name="department" id="department"></select>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're setting the value and text to `array`. You probably mean `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `arr` which represents single array element instead of `array`:

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];

array.forEach(function(arr) {
  $(".department").append('<option value="' + arr + '">' + arr + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="department" name="department" id="department"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this:

```
var options = array.map(function(arr) {
  return '<option value="' + arr + '">' + arr + '</option>'
});

$(".department").html(options.join(''))
```

This method has performance benefits because accessing the DOM is expensive, more if you access it in every iteration of a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using JavaScript

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];

var select = document.getElementById("department");
array.map(function(item){
 var option = document.createElement("option");
 option.value = item;
 option.text  = item;
 select.appendChild(option)
});
```

```html
<select name="department" id="department"></select>
```